# How to update nested object property in array by id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

How can i updated isCompleted property to **true** on onClick. I can only access moduleContent id from route e.g.- "id": "cr1mod1content1". How can i update isCompleted property to true by only matching this id. Note: i'm using react/nextJS for this project.
here is my json data structure.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "progress": 0,
    "title": "Python Basics for Data Science",
    "modules": [
      {
        "id": "cr1mod1",
        "title": "Module 1- Python Basics",
        "moduleContent": [
          {
            "type": "html",
            "id": "cr1mod1content1",
            "title": "Module Introduction and Learning Objectives",
            "content": " <p>      This module teaches the basics of Python and begins  </p>",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "video",
            "id": "cr1mod1content2",
            "title": "Video: Types (3:02)",
            "content": "https://vimeo.com/23",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "quiz",
            "id": "cr1mod1content3",
            "title": "Practice Quiz: Types",
            "content": "",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "cr1mod2",
        "title": "Module 2 - Python Data Structures",
        "moduleContent": [
          {
            "type": "html",
            "id": "cr1mod2content1",
            "title": "Module Introduction and Learning Objectives",
            "content": " <p>This module begins a journey into Python data structure</p> ",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "video",
            "id": "cr1mod2content2",
            "title": "Video: Types (8:31)",
            "content": "https://vimeo.com/1",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "quiz",
            "id": "cr1mod2content3",
            "title": "Practice Quiz: Types",
            "content": "",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this in this way:

```
const arr = declare Your JSON array there
const id = 'cr1mod2content3'
for(const module of arr[0].modules) {
    for(const item of module.moduleContent) {
        if(item.id === id) item.isCompleted = true
    }
}
```

Take into account that if your root JSON array may contain several elements, you will have to wrap the cycle with one more (root) iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [some() of array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for checking and update

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "progress": 0,
    "title": "Python Basics for Data Science",
    "modules": [
      {
        "id": "cr1mod1",
        "title": "Module 1- Python Basics",
        "moduleContent": [
          {
            "type": "html",
            "id": "cr1mod1content1",
            "title": "Module Introduction and Learning Objectives",
            "content": " <p>      This module teaches the basics of Python and begins  </p>",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "video",
            "id": "cr1mod1content2",
            "title": "Video: Types (3:02)",
            "content": "https://vimeo.com/23",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "quiz",
            "id": "cr1mod1content3",
            "title": "Practice Quiz: Types",
            "content": "",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "cr1mod2",
        "title": "Module 2 - Python Data Structures",
        "moduleContent": [
          {
            "type": "html",
            "id": "cr1mod2content1",
            "title": "Module Introduction and Learning Objectives",
            "content": " <p>This module begins a journey into Python data structure</p> ",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "video",
            "id": "cr1mod2content2",
            "title": "Video: Types (8:31)",
            "content": "https://vimeo.com/1",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          },
          {
            "type": "quiz",
            "id": "cr1mod2content3",
            "title": "Practice Quiz: Types",
            "content": "",
            "quizContent": [],
            "isCompleted": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
const updateData = (arr, idFilter) => {
  arr.some(({modules}) => {
    modules.some(({moduleContent}) => {
      moduleContent.some(ele => {
        if (ele.id === idFilter) {
          return ele.isCompleted = true
        }
        return false
      })
    })
  })
}
updateData(data, 'cr1mod1content1')
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map** double times to update

```
 data[0].modules.map(item => item.moduleContent.map(obj => {
    if (obj.id === "cr1mod1content1") {
        obj.isCompleted = true
    }
}));
```